# How to give taller/scrollable element get height of shorter sibling in flex?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, position, height

I am deling with this weird issue, that I dont know if there is an answer to but I really need it.

I have a flex container which has:

display: flex;
flex-direction: row;

The element on the right is an element that can be of variable height depending on information pulled from database.

The element on the left has flex direction column. And in there I have some tabs, search bar, and then I have a list which a lot of the times can be longer and thus have the height higher than the element on the right.

What I need is for that list not to occupy all the space that it would with all the items, I want it to be scrollable and to fit exactly up to the footer of my website. For that I need to specifiy a certain height to make the div with the list scrollable. But if the element on the right has more content that the height I gave the list...the height of that div should also stretch so as there is no space between my list and the footer of my website.

I researched a lot of answers with similar problem but I couldn't find nothing that worked for me.

I made a video to better exemplify the problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkOOukuYF1U

Please help, I really need to know if there is way to make this happen, if not with css maybe with javascript?

For reference, I am working on this website in React.

Comment: Hi Talmacel, for people on SO to help you, you need to post a [reprex].

Comment: Talmacel, please re-post the video. the link is dead.